# What weapons count for the "kill an enemy with every type of weapon" Abstergo challenge?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

Under the Fighter category, there's a challenge to kill an enemy with every type of weapon, and a count of nine.

What weapons count toward the completion of the challenge?

[image: Screenshot of the Fighter challenge category.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any plausible killing weapon, so it would be

- Duel Swords
- Pistols
- Hidden Blades
- Rope Dart
- Heavy Axe(dropped by the Heavy British Soldiers)
- Sword (dropped by the soldiers)
- Musket (dropped by the soldiers)
- Swivel Gun
- Throwing knife (dropped by agile guards)

Comment: Beserk dart seems like an obvious one that kills people (if they survive their mates trying to kill them). Don't know if that is the missing 9th but I'm struggling to think of others. Sinking their ship with your cannons maybe... :)

Comment: I just checked my game and I'm on the same boat as you, hmm it's weird I'm going to look into to this, but I'm only missing one I already have the rope dart.

Comment: I'm on 7/9 and I think I have all of those except the heavy axe. I've also just remembered the throwing knife thing. Oh, I might not have a soldiers sword actually, just my own ones...

Comment: I'm at 7/9 as well, and I've used every conceivable weapon I've seen, except for the Rope Dart, which I haven't gotten yet.

Comment: I wonder do the golden gun count

Comment: @Charkz I've used the regular pistols and the golden guns, no difference, still at 7/9. I'm wondering now if there's something bugged here.

Comment: It may seem counterintuitive but have you tried an assassination with bare hands?